# How to outline objects from a picture in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I was wondering how to draw bounding boxes around objects in an image using FLutter.
Neither Image picker nor Image cropper does it.

I would like to let the user select an image from gallery (done) and would like to let him draw boxes around objects and use it in the code.

Thanks for the help